# How to properly center align text in titlepage?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I am trying to properly center the phrase "Faculty of Engineering", but haven't been able. I really can't understand why it isn't properly centered since I have included everything in the `\begin{center}` environment. Could use some help here!

Here is the script with the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,ifthen}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes,
                calc}
\tikzset{
block/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  rectangle, 
  minimum height=3em, 
  minimum width=4em,
  text centered, 
  text width=2cm
  },
sum/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  circle, 
  },
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={
  pin edge={to-,thin,black}
  }
}  


\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
    
        \begin{center}
            
            \Large
            \textbf{Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης}
            \newline
            \Large
            \textbf{\textlatin{Faculty of Engineering}}
            \newline
            \Large
            \textbf{Τμήμα Ηλεκτρολόγων Μηχανικών και Μηχανικών Ηλεκτρονικών Υπολογιστών}
            \newline
            \Large
            \textbf{Τομέας Ηλεκτρονικής και Υπολογιστών}
            
            

        \end{center}
            
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove all the `\newline`  commands and all except the first `\Large` commands and leave at least one empty line between items

Comment: The first \Large is sufficient for the entire center environment.  Note that \\ is redefiined for center, but not \newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this --added common `textbf` and `Large` commands for title
[image]

```
\begin{titlepage}
                \begin{center}
            
            \Large\textbf{%<-------------------------------add % and textbf
            {Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης}\\
            {\textlatin{Faculty of Engineering}}\\
            {Τομέας Ηλεκτρονικής και Υπολογιστών}
            }%<--------------------------------------------add%
            
            
        \end{center}
        
    \end{titlepage}
```